Разноцветный ввод в консоль
У меня недавно появилось желание создать bash-приложение на c/c++. Я решил создать разноцветный ввод (именно ввод) в консоль (например как в powershell на windows). Но я нигде не смог найти ничего подобного в интернете, как осуществить мою задумку.

Например вот так: start жёлтым цветом, а app.exe - белым.
Ещё раз напоминаю - не вывод, а ввод.

Открою секрет: в консоли ввод не отображается, отображается вывод.

Алгоритм достаточно простой, рассмотрим на примере из вопроса. Команда подсвечивается жёлтым, первой во вводе ожидаем команду. Значит, нужно получать нажатые клавиши (не всю строку целиком) и отображать символы на экране жётым. Пробел - конец команды, анализ. Если команда не найдена, то затёрли и напечатали то же самое красным. Если команда распознана, то дальше аргументы отображаем белым.
using System;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        char ch;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        while ((ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 13) {
            if (ch == 32) Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
}


Только есть вопрос: как закрасить отдельный символ или команду после их считывания в программе? А не до их записи?

Console.ForegroundColor Property Ожидаем команду - ставим жёлтый. Считываем нажатия клавиш. Когда нужно, меняем цвет.

Добавил пример.

Язык другой ...

@user7860670 От этого алгоритм не меняется, и консоль та же самая.

Дело в том, что в с++ подобного нет.

Я бы иначе не спросил.

Да не может такого быть... Вот, например. А это я ещё в документацию не лез.

@DanielHunter, для реализации данного предложения вам нужно забыть о вводе символов в стиле С++, а читать символы с терминала по мере их ввода (можете посмотреть на termios). Также придется самому программировать все редактирование набираемой строки (забой и т.п.)

@avp, думаю вы правы. Я уже наткнулся на эту библиотеку.

@DanielHunter, если  вы намечаете что-то большее, чем студенческая поделка, то посмотрите на GNU readline. Наверное прикрутить к ней нужную вам раскраску будет не слишком сложно

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char ch;
    system("color 0E"); // Ставим цвет консоли на жёлтый
    while ((ch = _getch()) != '\n') { 
        if (ch == '\0') {
            system("color 0F"); // Ставим цвет консоли белый.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Этот код работает также, как код rotabot-а, только он написан на С++.
Здесь цвет устанавливается с помощью функции system("color код"). Здесь код - это шестнадцатеричный код цвета. Вам надо знать эти коды для установки цветов консоли.

Нет. Не работает.
